# How do I access the exploding task switcher in Plasma?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

When I used Debian, until last week, using alt tab, or hitting the super key, would sort of explode all the various higgledy piggledy windows into an array so they were all visible (but shrunken), allowing me to click the one I wanted... (sorry it's a poor description)

I really liked this, but I've gone through all the task switcher modules however and none of them is like this, the closest being grid.

To tease me, I have twice somehow triggered this behaviour I seek accidentally (uuugh!!) and been unable to figure out what I did.

Please, can anyone tell me how I get it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you might find [this](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html) useful.

Comment: I did find it useful, Ctrl+F9, described as "present Windows on current desktop" is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help with this irritation!

Comment: Always [Eager to help](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for "Present Windows"

```
Ctrl+F10    Present Windows
Ctrl+F9 Present Windows on current desktop
```

One of these should produce the desired result.

Source:

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html